# Where to download images to in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I was working with an xcode project(game with cocos2d) that uses a lot of sprites. The thing is I would want to download images from the URL to a local directory on the device, so that i can use them later to create sprites.

So what would be the best location to download the images to? I can create a folder reference inside my projects folder, but is that a good way to go about it? Is there a standard practice to this?

I read that there are iphone which can be used for this? 
Please let me know if there are resources that can help me understand these better....

Thanx

Comment: try saving in `NSDocumentsDirectory` or the Library Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download all images form the URl to DocumentDirectory and you can use it later, as a part of your game. I am using the following code to download Images

```
NSArray* path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
        docPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageName.png"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:o] valueForKey:@"Image_Question"]]]];
NSData* imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imgData writeToFile:docPath atomically:YES];
```

And when you want to retrieve for any usage in application you can use the following code

```
UIImage* imageFormDoc = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:docPath];
```

and when you want to delete the image form the Document Directory you can use the following code.

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:docPath error: &error];

**docPath** is the full path of Document Directory with Image then you can Print Using NSLog for detail information.*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,
You can save all the images to the Document folder of the Application and later on , you can use all the images in your application.

Comment: So this 'Documents folder' is part of the library that is being provided to work with dynamic content?

Comment: Yes you can use it with dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

try saving in NSDocumentsDirectory or the Library Directory and u can get it from the plist

Comment: Can you plese tell me what would be the path to the library directory?